# Android 11 Audiopolicy cannot recognize two USB sound cards at the same time。

Tags: android, audio, frameworks, usb

I have two USB devices with microphones, one is a USB headset and the other is a USB camera.

The insertion order will affect the recognition of the sound card by Audiopolicy

When I insert the USB headset first and then the USB camera, Available Devices can only identify the microphone device of the USB camera, but not any device of the USB headset.
If the USB camera is inserted first and then the USB headset is inserted, Available Devices can only recognize the USB headset and microphone, but not the microphone of the USB camera.

But inside the kernel, the USB camera microphone and USB headset microphone are working properly, and tinyCap or tinyPlay can be used for record and playback.

Is there a mechanism in Android Audiopolicy that only recognizes the last plugged USB sound card device?

I needed it to recognize more than two USB sound card devices at the same time, and then I went to the Engine to switch it myself.  How should I do that?
Where is the code to load the USB sound card into Audiopolicy Available Devices?

Looking forward to your reply. Thank you very much!

I uploaded the relevant logs in the form of pictures:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fk9mZ.jpg)

Comment: You should clarify if you are creating a Custom ROM/device or trying to use consumer hardware device (retail phones & tablets). Just in case you aren't aware of: https://source.android.com/devices/audio/implement-policy

Comment: My device is a custom Android tablet running Android 11

Comment: There is a lot of information. As a novice, I don't know what else needs to be provided. Please forgive me.  If there is anything missing, please remind me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem has already been settled.

```
--- /frameworks/base/services/usb/java/com/android/server/usb/UsbAlsaManager.java   2022-06-17 20:12:08.000000000 +0800
+++ /frameworks/base/services/usb/java/com/android/server/usb/UsbAlsaManager.java   2022-08-23 10:25:17.677554569 +0800
@@ -48,7 +48,7 @@ public final class UsbAlsaManager {
 
     // Flag to turn on/off multi-peripheral select mode
     // Set to true to have single-device-only mode
-    private static final boolean mIsSingleMode = true;
+    private static final boolean mIsSingleMode = false;
 
     private static final String ALSA_DIRECTORY = "/dev/snd/";
```